# dart web ui webcomponents extending off html elements in future

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I read this on darts web ui intro page.

> The constructor attribute indicates the class that defines this
>   component’s behavior (for example, “CounterComponent”). Today, this
>   class must be a subclass of WebComponent, but in the future it will be
>   possible to use a subclass of the HTML element declared in the extends
>   attribute. In the preceding example, that would mean class
>   CounterComponent extends DivElement ....

Have they said when this change is scheduled and will it require old components that do extend WebComponent will need to be rewritten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know when/if this will happen but the WebComponent class features the following comment:

```
  /**
   * Temporary property until components extend [Element]. An element can
   * only be associated with one host, and it is an error to use a web component
   * without an associated host element.
   */
  Element get host { ... }
```

Since it says "temporary" I guess that if your code is explicitly referring to `host`, some changes will be required.